# Can anyone provide an example on how to use timepicker with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, timepicker

I'm using rails 4.1.6 under Ruby 2.1.3, if that's relevant. The gem I'm using is bootstrap-timepicker-rails from https://github.com/tispratik/bootstrap-timepicker-rails.

It's a new project, so I have added very little to it, other than basic functionality I use on every project. All I want is to be able to use timepicker like it's used in the first example of http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

So far, I have this in a partial view (from a table inside a form_for):

```
%tr
  %td=f.text_field :time, :class => 'timepicker'
```

And this on its js.coffee:

```
$(document).on 'focus', ".timepicker", ->
  $(this).timepicker()
```

And it behaves erratically. The fieldbox that contains the timepicker tries to show a time, but it locks at 12:00 am, and nothing else happens. I tried adding several other classes, including copying the source html code of the example I tried to use, but it doesn't work. No errors on the browser console either.

What am I missing?

Here're my relevant config files:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'hirb'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails.git'
gem 'bootstrap-timepicker-rails'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '= 2.1.10.0.3'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require jquery-ui/core
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/core
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.js
//= require bootstrap-timepicker
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

//= require global

//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
*= require bootstrap-datepicker3
*= require bootstrap_files.css.scss
*= require bootstrap-timepicker

*= require global
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Apparently the issue is that I'm using bootstrap3 instead of boostrap2, which the gem I mentioned seems to be designed for. I'm going to search for a gem that can work with bootstrap3; I'll update when/if I find it.

Comment: I would not use `on focus`. I would use [ready instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links) and use `$('.timepicker').timepicker();`

Comment: I have to use on focus, since the form is dynamic. The text_field can appear and vanish as I move other stuff in the form. With `ready` the javascript would not be loaded for the subsequent ones created via jQuery.

Comment: ... and just to test it, it has the same effect I'm experiencing right now with `on focus`.

Comment: Looks like others have had this issue: https://github.com/tispratik/bootstrap-timepicker-rails/issues/15

Comment: I just realized that the gem hasn't been touched in 2 years. Oh well. Guess I'll have to use something else. Thanks for pointing that out.